# run a prog. from command line in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line

How to run a python program from command line and pass an argument to it?

Someone, please help me with this problem I have tried but I'm not able to do so.

Comment: using the argparse module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very basic example using sys,

```
import sys
for x in sys.argv:
  print(f'Argument: {x}')
```

I'm using fstring which will work in python 3.6 if you're using 3.5 you can use print function as

```
print("Argument: ",x)
```

You can then run this file, whatever you've named it as

```
python filename.py hello
```

You'll get the following output,

```
Argument:  test.py
Argument:  hello
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question a bit unclear for me but I'll try to answer. If you run .py extension file from the command line without virtualenv. just type:

```
python filename.py
```

Make sure you already in python folder.

But if you have virtualenv. you can run python anywhere using the same command or just type:

```
path/file_name.py
```

But if you confused on how to run compiled python file or you've make an exe from python file make sure you put `input()` in the end to hold the screen or put your code under a conditional loop.

IF you want to run command line from your python program try use subprocess module.